# Read a line from file, using stream style

Tags: c++, stl, stream

I have a simple text file, that has following content

```
word1 word2
```

I need to read it's first line in my C++ application.
Following code works, ...

```
std::string result;
std::ifstream f( "file.txt" );
f >> result;
```

... but **result** variable will be equal to "word1". It should be equal to "word1 word2" (first line of text file)
Yes, i know, that i can use readline(f, result) function, but is there a way to do the same, using >> style. This could be much more pretty.
Possible, some manipulators, i don't know about, will be useful here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Use `getline(f, result)` to read a line.

Answer (score 4):

Yes define a line class and define the operator >> for this class.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


struct Line
{
    std::string line;

    // Add an operator to convert into a string.
    // This allows you to use an object of type line anywhere that a std::string
    // could be used (unless the constructor is marked explicit).
    // This method basically converts the line into a string.
    operator std::string() {return line;}
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str,Line& line)
{
    return std::getline(str,line.line);
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,Line const& line)
{
    return str << line.line;
}

void printLine(std::string const& line)
{
    std::cout << "Print Srting: " << line << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Line    aLine;
    std::ifstream f( "file.txt" );
    f >> aLine;

    std::cout << "Line: " << aLine << "\n";
   printLine(aLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local that only has newlines as whitespace, but that would be a confusing hack. [Here is an example doing just that with commas.](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.comp.lang.learn.c-c++/msg/db55ffea728c5cf9?dmode=source&pli=1)